# insert ignore on duplicate entries in Doctrine2/Symfony2

Tags: doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to ignore on duplicate entries using Doctrine2?

Error example:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'symfony' for key 'UNIQ_389B783389B783'
```

Comment: You can do what propel do: make a method like findByKeyOrCreate(), returning an existent entity if any or creating a new one if not.

Comment: Remove `@Unique` index from that field, if you don't need it.

Comment: What result do you expect from it, when try to save not-unique entry?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's one of the nuisances of Doctrine, it's not possible to do INSERT/UPDATE Ignore, there are workaround like creating a methods that checks if the row exists, and if it does then just skip it.

You can catch the exception, so that your script doesn't end in an exception. However, the entity manager will be closed and you will not be able to use it anymore. You can still use PDO, though and you can insert a record in the database indicating that your batch failed because `X` and it needs to be restarted (that's what I usually do).

If none of the options above work for you, ultimately I end up writing raw SQL to do batch processing and I don't use Doctrine at all, it ends up being faster and the ability of doing INSERT/UPDATE Ignore makes it a no brainer.

Comment: If you don't mind overriding items you can Use merge as In https://stackoverflow.com/a/15838232/1454173 (is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0)

Answer (score 23):

In **Symfony 3** you can reset manager and continue working with it by calling `resetManager()` method of `Doctrine` object after catching `UniqueConstraintViolationException` exception.

Here is an example:

```
try {
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $entity = Product::create()
    ->setTitle('Some title')
    ->setUrl('http://google.com');
  $em->persist($entity);
  $em->flush();
}
catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException $e) {
  $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
}
```

Comment: Nice share! (i.e. resetManager())

Comment: I would be interested in a more recent answer of that type. resetManager() is now deprecated.

Comment: if you are using symfony 3/4 use

`composer require symfony/proxy-manager-bridge`

Answer (score 13):

You can always catch the exception and then ignore it.  Just be aware that when the entity manager raises an exception, the entity manager can no longer be used during that request.

Answer (score 1):

This problem answer. Symfony >=4.0 and Doctrine >= 2.0

My Entity Uniq Fields **phone** and **channel**

Import this class on your entity class

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\NotifyPropertyChanged;
use Doctrine\Persistence\PropertyChangedListener;
```

After implements NotifyPropertyChanged class

```
class TblPersonPhonePermission implements NotifyPropertyChanged
```

After addPropertyChangedListener methods

```
public function addPropertyChangedListener(PropertyChangedListener $listener)
{
    $insertBatch = $listener->getScheduledEntityInsertions();
    foreach ($insertBatch as $entity) {
        if (
            (get_class($entity) === get_class($this)) &&
            $this->getId() !== $entity->getId() &&
            $this->getPhone() === $entity->getPhone() &&
            $this->getChannel() === $entity->getChannel()
        ) {
            $listener->remove($this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for duplicates before actually inserting. I had a similar issue and answered it here: [doctrine/symfony 4 - avoid duplicate entry when persisting child entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275181/doctrine-symfony-4-avoid-duplicate-entry-when-persisting-child-entities/57275578#57275578)

```
protected function removeDuplicates($insertions) {
    foreach ($insertions as $key => $insertion) {
        $shortClassName = (new ReflectionClass($insertion))->getShortName();
        // TODO: The search can be heavily optimized
        foreach ($insertions as $possibleDupeKey => $possibleDupeInsertion) {
            $shortDupeClassName = (new ReflectionClass($insertion))->getShortName();
            // TODO: Treat case when unique is on a field not called 'id'
            if ($shortClassName === $shortDupeClassName && $insertion->getId() === $possibleDupeInsertion->getId() && $key !== $possibleDupeKey) {
                $this->em->remove($possibleDupeInsertion);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected function saveStuff($order) {
    $this->em->persist($order);
    $this->removeDuplicates($this->em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions());
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: This is useful only in case you are saving duplicates inside one thread, which is the easier case. The problem is usually that two threads (two server requests) are trying to create the same thing simultaneously.