# Symfony2 Doctrine merge

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am studying https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html but I cannot figure out what cascade merge does. I have seen elsewhere that

```
$new_object = $em->merge($object);
```

basically creates a new managed object based on `$object`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$em->merge()` is used to take an Entity which has been taken out of the context of the entity manager and 'reattach it'.

- If the Entity was never managed, merge is equivalent to persist.
- If the Entity was detached, or serialized (put in a cache perhaps) then merge more or less looks up the id of the entity in the data store and then starts tracking any changes to the entity from that point on.

Cascading a merge extends this behavior to associated entities of the one you are merging. This means that changes are cascaded to the associations and not just the entity being merged.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I also had a similar problem, after the entity manager got closed and I had to reset the manager. What happened was that entities which should be updated, got insert statement and ofcourse the foreign key constraint error appeared. Using $em->merge() solved it for me, because it marked the entity as managed again.

Comment: I know this answer is old, but just for reference, merge() will be removed in Doctrine3 https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/UPGRADE.md

Comment: I use it at the moment with FOS REST bundle when I use the JMS serializer to get the JSON into an entity with relations and that entity I got cascade merge. If I don't use the merge the cascade is ignored as it uses reflection and the setter doesn't set correctly to have the ref Id from child to parent table. I don't know if there is a better solution than using Merge?

Comment: After fetching entity from cache, I used merge to persist it. But what is the replacement if it is going to deprecate?

Comment: well, I'm also building an entity from the cache, and passing it as the relation of another entity, and with cascade persists it's trying to create a new entry in DB instead of just associate it. Also if I just making persist on the entity it also trying to make new DB entry. So looks like in my case persist ignoring a facto that id is exists and trying to insert record to DB, not sure why maybe b-z I'm using UUID? And it only works for me when I'm doing merge. Cascade merge also not working.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question, but I think it is worth mentioning that `$em->merge()` is deprecated and will be removed soon. [Check here](https://github.com/doctrine/persistence/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/ObjectManager.php)

> Merge operation is deprecated and will be removed in Persistence 2.0.
>   Merging should be part of the business domain of an application rather
>   than a generic operation of ObjectManager.

Also please read this doc v3 how they expect entities to be stored

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html#entities-in-the-session

> It is a good idea to avoid storing entities in serialized formats such
>   as $_SESSION: instead, store the entity identifiers or raw data.