# Symfony 3 UniqueEntity validation on update

Tags: symfony

I am facing an issue with UniqueEntity validation. 
I have a field "internal_asset_number" which should be unique and it's working fine on create. On update when i edit the existing current data with the same values, it shows "There is already an asset with that internal number!" but it shouldn't because it's the same entry.

The entity:

```
/**
* Asset
*
* @ORM\Table(schema="assets", name="asset", uniqueConstraints=    {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="uk_asset_internal_asset_number_client_id", columns={"internal_asset_number", "client_id"})})
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Api\AssetBundle\Entity\AssetRepository")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"internalAssetNumber"}, groups={"post", "put"}, message="There is already an asset with that internal number!")
*/
class Asset
   {
   /**
    * @var guid
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
    */
   private $id;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="client_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
    */
   private $clientId;

   /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="internal_asset_number", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
    */
   private $internalAssetNumber;
```

Update method:

```
public function putAssetAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $this->deserializer('Api\AssetBundle\Entity\Asset', $request, 'put');
    if ($data instanceof \Exception) {
        return View::create(['error' => $data->getMessage()], 400);
    }

    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($data, null, 'put');

    if (count($errors) > 0) {         
        $errorsResponse = [];
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $errorsResponse = $error->getMessage();
        }
        return View::create(array('error' => $errorsResponse), 400);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: How do you do the update? What do you mean by "blocked"? What error do you get?

Comment: @JakubMatczak I get the error message i have set when it's duplicated. But in this case i update the same entry with the same values so it shouldn't happen. I updated my question.

Comment: When there is an existing entry in the database for the given criteria, the `UniqueEntityValidator` will check if the object being validated and the found object are the same (i.e. it performs an identity check). This check fails in your case as the object being validated in your case is the deserialized one, but not the one managed by Doctrine.

Comment: @xabbuh Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @xabbuh commented, the problem is that the entity you persist after update is not retrieved through the entityManager so when you persist it the entity manager thinks it is a new entity.

Here is how to solve it:

```
$entityManager->merge($entity);
```

This will tell the entitymanager to merge your serialized entity with the managed one

Some more explanation on `merge()`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15838232/5758328