# Symfony 2, createForm delete relations of Entity

Tags: symfony, php-5.6

I retrieve an object from the session that I insert in a form. But I do not understand why the relation of my entity with other objects is reset when i create a new form.

my code :

```
$devis = $em->merge($session->get("devis")) ;

dump($devis->getCentre()->getId()); // = 2

$form = $this->createForm($devis_type, $devis, array(...));

dump($devis->getCentre()->getId()); // = null
```

Then in my view it's not keep the relationship in the choice list.

Comment: did you persist `devis`?

Comment: No i don't, I want to fill my object on several pages before the registration in database. According to this post, merge is similar to persist in this context : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833639/symfony2-doctrine-merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had to do this :

```
$centre = $devis->getCentre();
$session->set("devis",$devis);
$session->set("centre",$centre);
```

And after :

```
$devis = $em->merge($session->get("devis")) ;
$centre = $em->merge($session->get("centre")) ;
$devis->setCentre($centre);
```

And my form work well.