# Doctrine: Avoid duplicates in same insert process

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is there a built in way / recommendation to handle duplicate entries while entities are inserted without a flush for each entry?

Lets assume we have a person entity with two fields. ID and personalNr.
ID is the primary key but personalNr has also a unique constraint.

Now i am iterating over a csv file where one personalNr can be listed in multiple rows.

If the row contains a personalNr, I check against the repository if a entry with this personalNr exist. If yes, i link the dataset to the person with the personalNr. If no, i create a new person with the personalNr and link it afterwards with the dataset.

The problem now is:

If a personalNr occurs more than once in a csv file, the dataset already exists in the entity manager when i find it again, but its unsaved to the database yet (i called no flush until now). The check against the repository will say "There is no entity in the repository" but the entity manager will throw an duplicate entry exception on flush cause it tries to create multiple entities with the same personalNr.

How to avoid this? Is the only way to save what was already inserted or not by myself? Has doctrine such a checking mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: I think this will answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699613/insert-ignore-on-duplicate-entries-in-doctrine2-symfony2

Comment: Nothing builtin to Doctrine.  I just make myself an array of personalNr values and check the array as I process each row.  I might add that dropping down to straight sql if far more performant for imports with a significant number of entries.

Comment: I am very unhappy with this situation. That means much more overhead and logic in modules which are not responsible for such things. Thank you.